# sshd on different port than 22: different in OL7 vs EL5?

Tags: ssh

I can connect to a box with EL5 (Oracle EL5 in my case) if I use a command such as: `/usr/sbin/sshd -4 -p 10222` to start sshd on that box.

... but in EL7 it flat out doesn't work. Is there a reason for this? What changed?

Sample attempt:

```
[root@oel5 ~]# ssh -p 10222 -vvv -x -l test ol7
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ol7" port 10222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ol7 [a.b.c.d] port 10222.
debug1: connect to address a.b.c.d port 10222: No route to host
ssh: connect to host a.b.c.d port 10222: No route to host
```

Comment: Did you reconfigure sshd to listen on the port ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to enable that port on firewalld:
`firewall-cmd --add-port=10222/tcp --permanent` and then `firewall-cmd --reload`
Second, you have to check out SELinux. If it's enabled you need to add that port context with `semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 10222`